# WHMCS Problem when add order via LocalAPI

Tags: php, api, whmcs

I have 2 problem with [WHMCS LocalAPI](https://developers.whmcs.com/api/internal-api/).

#### (1) I have a problem when I add order to client via LocalAPI.

I use a webservice where I must send my request to a web service and if returned `true` then I must add a order to client, but when I use addorder API the WHMCS apply credit automatically and it is not suitable for me. I want to add order and DO NOT paid invoice through credit.

#### (2)

I have a additional domain field in `domainadditionalfields` in whmcs database that fieldname as figure, but I do not know what syntax is true I use this code but value field is `empty`:

[image]

```
$command = 'AddOrder';
$postData = array(
    'clientid' => 701,
    'domain' => array($domain),
    'domaintype' => array('register'),
    'regperiod' => array($period),
    'nameserver1' => $ns1,
    'nameserver2' => $ns2,
    'additionalfields["irnichandle"]' => "ABC",
    'paymentmethod' => 'mailin',
    'applycredit' => false,
);
$adminUsername = 'adminuser'; // Optional for WHMCS 7.2 and later

$results = localAPI($command, $postData, $adminUsername);
$orderid = $result['orderid'];
$invoiceid = $result['invoiceid'];
print_r($results);
```

Comment: Improved formatting.

Answer (score 0):

(1) There is an option to disable auto applying credit, Setup > General Settings > Credit > Automatic Credit Use (untick it)

(2)  For additional fields, you should use `domainfields` parameter in the AddOrder function as following:

`'domainfields' => array(base64_encode(serialize(array($firstFieldValue))))`

Docs:

- [Additional Domain Fields](https://docs.whmcs.com/Additional_Domain_Fields)
- [Automatic Credit Application](https://docs.whmcs.com/Credit/Prefunding#Automation).